# How can I flag missing start/end dates per account in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas related question. My dataframe has daily records of unique account numbers:

| Account | Date | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/2022 | 132 |
| 1 | 03/02/2022 | 133 |
| 1 | 03/03/2022 | 135 |
| 2 | 03/02/2022 | 44 |
| 2 | 03/03/2022 | 48 |
| 3 | 03/01/2022 | 65 |
| 3 | 03/02/2022 | 67 |
| 4 | 03/01/2022 | 757 |
| 4 | 03/02/2022 | 788 |
| 4 | 03/03/2022 | 799 |

As you can see, account 2 is missing the first date (03/01/2022) a account 3 is missing 03/03/2022. I would like to be able to create 2 new columns to identify with a flag which of these accounts are new and which of these no longer exist due to a missing flag based on the min/max date.
Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea how to start on this.

Comment: is the date DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: Sorry, the date is MM/DD/YYYY. Each df only has a months of data so i'm trying to catch if the min and max of the dates (first and last available) match all of the accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the min/max date per group and compare to the absolute min/max, then assign boolean columns:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)
g = s.groupby(df['Account'])
df['client left'] = g.transform('max').ne(s.max())  # or lt (<)
df['new client'] = g.transform('min').ne(s.min())   # or gt (>)
```

*NB. you can also use fixed references instead of the computed global min/max.*

output:

```
   Account        Date  Balance  client left  new client
0        1  03/01/2022      132        False       False
1        1  03/02/2022      133        False       False
2        1  03/03/2022      135        False       False
3        2  03/02/2022       44        False        True
4        2  03/03/2022       48        False        True
5        3  03/01/2022       65         True       False
6        3  03/02/2022       67         True       False
7        4  03/01/2022      757        False       False
8        4  03/02/2022      788        False       False
9        4  03/03/2022      799        False       False
```

##### alternative output

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)
g = s.groupby(df['Account'])

out = pd.DataFrame({'new client': g.min().ne(s.min()),    # or gt (>)
                    'client left': g.max().ne(s.max())})  # or lt (<)

print(out)
```

output:

```
         new client  client left
Account                         
1             False        False
2              True        False
3             False         True
4             False        False
```